# OAuth code grant flow for internal auth token issuing

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have a requirement to integrate a React SPA with a third party auth provider. In addition, my app will use my own internal JWT for auth so that we are decoupled from the third party provider apart from the initial user authentication. This also allows us to add our own custom claims to the JWT. All internal API calls at the backend will use the internal JWT, via an API gateway. My proposed flow is as follows:

## Auth Flow

1. User requests my React app at `web.acme.com`.
2. App uses a protected route to check if the user is logged in. It does this by checking if there is a JWT in local/session storage, and if so it makes a POST request to my auth service at `api.acme.com/authorize` to check if the JWT is valid (200 or 401 response).
3. If not logged in, the app displays a login page. User clicks the login button and browser loads the login URL for a third party auth provider `foo.com`.
4. When user authenticates they are redirected to `api.acme.com/login?code=abc123`, i.e. they are redirected to my own auth service now with the access code.
5. My auth service uses the access code to now request an access token from `foo.com` on the user's behalf. When the access token is retrieved my auth service now issues my own internal JWT with claims extracted from the `foo.com` token plus my own additional claims.
6. The auth service redirects the user back to the web app at `web.acme.com` and includes the JWT.
7. The React app loads again and repeats step (2). Since JWT is now present and valid the protected route is rendered.

## Questions

1. Does this flow make sense, i.e. is it OAuth 2.0 compatible? Are there any obvious flaws?
2. Is it possible to include the JWT in the redirect from step (6)? My understanding was that browsers ignore the body in a redirect. I want the browser to be redirected but also store the JWT in local/session storage, so the JWT has to be forwarded on the redirect for the React app to pick it up. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is on the right tracks, except that I am not sure if the recommended browser flow (Authorization Code + PKCE) is being implemented with all of the right checks? It is very tricky to implement this in an API.
2. To redirect from the API back to the web origin and supply the JWT there are 2 options:

- a. Include the JWT in the query string - but then you are potentially revealing the JWT to the browser and server logs.
- b. Set it in an HTTP Only encrypted cookie, then redirect to the web origin, from which another server call could get the JWT.

**TOKENS IN LOCAL STORAGE**

In 2021 it is not really recommended to store tokens in local storage, or even in the browser at all. Of course, the decision you make should depend on the sensitivity of your data and what your stakeholders think.

Short lived access tokens might be OK, but long lived refresh tokens are considered bad, due to various attack vectors, even when good input protection is coded. This [2021 video](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html) has further details.

There have been 2 related recent changes to browsers:

- `SameSite=strict` cookies have become stronger, with built-in CSRF protection, and are perceived to be more secure in the browser than OAuth tokens
- The traditional OAuth flow for SPAs allowed the SSO cookie from the Authorization Server to be used to get new short lived access tokens. But these are now likely to be seen as `third party` and dropped to prevent tracking (Safari does this). This means the only (non-cookie) way to solve usability problems such as page reloads is to store the refresh token in local storage, and this is considered poor from a security viewpoint.

**BACK END FOR FRONT END**

An SPA should therefore aim to store a refresh token in an HTTP Only encrypted secure cookie as its main credential. High security apps are also recommended to avoid access tokens in the browser.

The trend is to use something that handles tokens for the SPA and writes secure cookies. One option is to use an older 'web back end' technology, and another is to use an API driven approach.

**API DRIVEN SOLUTION**

These Curity resources show the latter option, which has similarities to the pattern you have described:

- [Code](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff)
- [Docs](https://curity.io/product/token-service/oauth-for-web/)

Here is the [React security code](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff/blob/main/code/spa/src/oauth/oauthClient.ts), where the SPA only makes API calls and the API never deals with redirects. The OpenID Connect messages sent by the API on behalf of the SPA are documented [here](https://curity.io/resources/learn/back-end-for-front-end/#browser-security-overview).

In terms of your question 2, we handle this by allowing the browser to receive the code, then send its full URL to the API. This keeps web and API concerns separated, and cannot be exploited by an attacker, since the code must be accompanied by both a PKCE code verifier and a client secret to get tokens.

**SUMMARY**

SPA security is hard unfortunately, and the extra cookie layer is inconvenient for web developers.

Comment: (1) I do use an Auth Service; it is generating JWT by authenticating user with code grant.

(2) Can you elaborate on the insecurity of local storage? My understanding was that this protects against CSRF as storage is only accessible by same domain that stored the data. Local/session storage are vulnerable to XSS but modern web frameworks such as React largely protect against this by santizing user input. For additional protection never load JavaScript from untrusted sources (e.g. CDN import).

(3) By using cookies I assume that adds extra complexity of CSRF protection.

Comment: I updated my answer - unfortunately it is a tricky topic - and of course it depends on the sensitivity of data involved.